# Should answers which slander other religions be allowed?

Tags: discussion

Richard claims that in "other religions" (by implication, *all* other religions), "[you see gods who do not care about individuals](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/510/214)". As I pointed out in a comment, this is [blatantly false](http://slacktivist.typepad.com/slacktivist/2011/07/101-wednesday-paganism.html) and completely and utterly ridiculous. Similar absurdities have been posted about [other religions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/677/214) in the past.

[El'endia Starman's answer to the question about "Eastern religions"](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/678/214) suggests some possibilities, but none work. In this case, comments explaining that the answer was wrong were ignored; editing without changing the import of the post is not possible, as the entire premise of the post rests on this absurd and somewhat slanderous claim; I did downvote, but Christians, it seems, are [ever-eager to believe ill of others](http://www.patheos.com/blogs/slacktivist/2012/07/23/wheaton-college-c-s-lewis-bad-jackie-on-preferring-the-nightmare-to-reality/), so the upvotes outweigh the downvotes.

Is this a place where flagging would be appropriate?

Comment: My first reaction to your question was "probably", but then I realized: what can/will we mods do about it? We're not going to edit it or delete it. [shrugs] What can we do?

Comment: First you say - "Should answers which slander other religions be allowed" And then - "*Christians, it seems, are ever-eager to believe ill of others*" Is it only me or does this question seem like a self contradictory rant? And what's next? Should answers criticizing a particular lifestyle be allowed? Sure let's ban everything until any kind of critical discussion is impossible and any attempt two discuss two contradictory ideas has someone running for the flag.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with above comment of Monika. There are different reasons for such answers. Some answer would not be answer until you refer and compare it with other religions. Sometimes answers referring to other religions just flows from question itself

When someone says on this site that they believe the present Bible is changed it is a slander for Christianity.  This has been said many times on this site. When they say that it was not Jesus who died but someone else in his place and that there was no resurrection, it is questioning the very foundation of Christianity and slander for Christianity.  Most Christians however take these comments as normal in a liberal society. This attitude is best described by Monika in her comments [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9516/is-christianity-threatened-in-these-times-because-of-its-too-much-of-tolerant).

Comment: No. That's a very different case. "Someone else died on the cross" is a statement of *belief*. And that's fine. "Pagans don't have a personal god" is a statement about *someone else's belief*. And getting that wrong is not acceptable at all. Furthermore, it completely undermines your argument.

Comment: @TRiG: That there _are no other gods_ and therefore there are no other religions with personal God is a belief held by Christianity. Right or wrong, our own beliefs necessarily include statements about the nature of other people's beliefs. That cannot be the definition of slander.

Comment: @Caleb. Maybe, if that's what Richard was saying. Which I doubt. I think Richard is talking about other religions' *beliefs*: the beliefs themseves, not the truth value of those beliefs. And I think he's overgeneralising and, in fact, objectively wrong. (Some religions don't have personal gods. Others definitely do.)